# Konva: how to vertical centering text

Tags: konvajs

I'm try to build a Konva Text container with vertical centering of it's content;

```
var infoText = new Konva.Text({
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  text: `my long long ... text`,
  fontSize: 18,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  align: 'center'
});
```

I found the *align* property in the docs, but it can only make text centered horizontally. How can I center vertically?

Comment: Updated my answer. It is much simpler to do it from v2.3.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to do from `Konva v2.3.0`:

```
const text = new Konva.Text({
  text: 'vertical align',
  x: 20,
  height: rect.height(),
  verticalAlign: 'middle'
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/budekuhopi/edit?html,js,output

**Old answer:**

At the current moment (v2.2.2), `Konva` can't do this automatically. You have to make manual adjustment:

```
const text = new Konva.Text({
  text: 'vertical align',
  x: 20,
});
layer.add(text);

text.y(containerHeight / 2 - text.getHeight() / 2);
```

http://jsbin.com/yakuwozaxi/2/edit?js,output